# Android animate in sequence

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I animate for example TextView1, TextView2 in sequence without creating more than one reference to fade in animation that they would appear one after another? The problem with below code that I need to create separate references and add listeners to each reference and if I would want to animate 10 views in sequence it would make my class really long with boilerplate code

What I'm doing right now:

```
private fun animateFirst(fadeIn: Animation) {
    fadeIn.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener{

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            animateSecond()
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}
    })

    textView1.startAnimation(fadeIn)
}

private fun animateSecond() {
    val fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in)
    textView2.startAnimation(fadeIn)
}
```

Comment: Use the same reference, if the Animation inst created with view.animate() you can reuse it

Comment: but if I set listener on that reference it fires after every animation

Comment: Since the method is called SET it should probably be overriden by another call to the method, just try to setListener with a empty implementation for the second one.